# how to set individual margins (left/right/top/bottom) with pandoc shell command when creating pdf?

Tags: linux, shell, pandoc

I'm pleased to see pandoc can specify some latex (which I know almost nothing of) geometries to customize the margin size of a pdf it creates like so....

`pandoc -V geometry:margin=.5in somefile.mkd --pdf-engine=xelatex -o output.pdf`

...but is there a way to make the side margins different from top/bottom margins?  Can each of the four (top/right/bottom/left) margin sizes be set individually?

I've tried options like `geometry:margin=.5in,2in` and `geometry:margin-side` and `geometry:margin-top` but none of those work.

From https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html these `margin-left, margin-right, margin-top, margin-bottom` should be able to be set individually but I can't figure out how to use them as commandline arguments.

Comment: If it's markdown -> PDF, you could also use the wkhtmltopdf backend and use CSS instead to get the margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
geometry:top=
geometry:right=
geometry:bottom=
geometry:left=
```

These options get passed to the LaTex [`geometry`](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package which means you can use any option supported by `geometry`.

The example in [pandoc’s manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex) even uses `top` and `left`.

Comment: it seems to be required to use `-V` for each setting.... `-V geometry:top=.5in -V geometry:left=1in`